# Bootstrap nav-bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web design and special twister boostrap .
I want to archive something like this :

- on mobile size when i click on navbar-toggle button , there will be a black layer with 0.7 opacity cover my page (but it doesnt cover my menu ) .
- then if i click anywhere on the black layer my navbar will back to normal ) and the black layer will disappear .

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read our [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend that you read this http://getbootstrap.com/ entire site more than once. If you are going to use Bootstrap you will need to get very very familiar with the entire framework to really take advantage of it.

Here is the NavBar section.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Also, here is a good example of tha bootstrap navbar.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/
If you resize the page to mobile size, you will see the navbar change to dropdown menu.

From my experience I leave the Bootstrap CSS file alone and create an override file. This way each time Bootstrap comes out with an update, you don't have to spend a bunch of time trying to correct all the changed styles in the new bootstrap.css. Or even worse the bootstrap.min.css.

As far as your question, on stack overflow you wil need to post your exisiting code that other users can assist with. But your question is very broad and it sounds like you want someone to write an entire navbar for you. Take that example page and make your own navbar page and then try to figure out how to achieve what you want, then if you are having issues with something, come back to Stackoverflow and ask for assistance on specific problems.

Comment: I feel that this answers your question to the best of Stack Overflows ability. If you feel the same, please click the check mark next to the up and down arrows.

Comment: I totally agree with leaving the Bootstrap CSS alone and manually overriding with another CSS file of my own. I see a lot of people fall down here as they forget they've updated their local version of Bootstrap CSS, then wonder why the documentation doesn't always apply or work as it says it should.